# Graphics driver being reported as Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300) instead of intel

Tags: intel-graphics

I have an integrated Intel 945GM in a Toshiba laptop. Previously the graphics driver was reported correctly, but at some point it has changed. I've noticed general poor performance and though it should meet minimum requirements for unity 3d is using unity 2d. Under the details panel in system settings it is now reporting Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300). any help would be appreciated. I have searched google for hours trying to find an answer.

Comment: How are your running llvmpipe - in 12.10 Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using 12.04. I never chose to run llvmpipe as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I might add that I have several repositories added to the official including ones for gnome, enlightenment, and Mesa. I had tried to use Elsa instead of compiz with no luck and no response from the community and reverted back to compiz a few months ago. This seems to be a more resent issue, but the exact timing is unknown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to edit xorg.conf in order to get this to work.  I had tried the instructions to create a xorg.conf file for 12.04 with no luck, giving me a "could not create lock file in /tmp/.tXO -lock" error. Running `man xorg.conf` it gave me several alternate locations to find it.  Hidden among the depths of the system in /etc/X11/ was xorg.conf. I had to change the  driver to "intel" and the description in my case "Intel 945gm". I then ran `sudo -i gedit` to edit the file to my needs. After a restart the correct driver is now in use.  Hope this can help someone else. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue too, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with a Intel core i5 and Intel Graphics 3000 exactly the same issue, happened just after an update today, is there any way to revert that to an previous state? I can't do a clean install because i have over 200 GB of data, and i can't backup so much data at this moment

> Edit: my computer is a Mac, not a Toshiba, so i don't think is a brand specific problem
>
> Edit: After a f*king lot of research i found that this command solves everything

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

And that's all...

Comment: this did not fix my problem as the Intel driver was installed but not in use.

Comment: I guess you'll have to investigate how to remove the pertinent driver it must be x-server-xorg-video-"something" I may provide more support if you'd give more details (graphics card, processor, etc)

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Ubuntu, the `xorg.conf` file doesn't exist but you can create a file to force the Intel driver.

First, create a directory:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Now, run the following command to create the config file:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat >/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf <<EOH
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
EOH'
```

Reboot or restart your xsession to apply the changes.