# DRAMATIC increase in CPU and failure to boot all of a sudden

Tags: boot

I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Toshiba Satellite Radius for a few months now and it ran beuatifully. Literally all of a sudden my computer refused to boot. I did a fresh intall of 14.04, using the same image I had used initially and still Ubuntu failed to boot - when I turned on the computer it just hung at a purple screen. I found these instructions

[Instructions](https://turriebuntu.wordpress.com/general-ubuntu-pages/ubuntu-boot-freeze-lockup-it-stops-with-a-blank-purple-or-black-screen/)

and I was finally ablt to get the PC to boot. However, there has been a DRAMATIC increase in CPU usage, such that hardly any applications are usable. For example, here is what `top` looks like when I launch SuperTuxKart, an application that worked fine before:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75qr.jpg)

I've done a clean install many times with the same outcome (the all of a sudden failure to boot/stuck on purple screen at boot is especially strange). Does anyone have a clue of how to start trouble shooting? Nothing has changed, could there be an issue with my CPU?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Two more commands: `lshw` (http://imgur.com/1ug6Y9I) and `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12` (http://imgur.com/4zxAm6Y)

Comment: yeah, what kind of CPU/GPU do you have? Also, when you are on the purple screen, you can press F2 to look at a verbose readout and it should have information listed when the system gets hung up. Please post what it says when it gets hung up and also any errors listed as well.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to capture verbose output but there are only 2 lines before it boots (after the fix posted above) `Unsupported SPIX Structure` and `Cannot turn on display power on i915`. Also, I think the two links in my comment above will answer the CPU/GPU question. If not, please advise me on how to find out this info. Also, I just installed Mint and this is not an issue there (neither the boot or the CPU issue). Maybe not my hardware then? Thanks.

Comment: So, unfortunately without `quiet splash nomodeset` the computer will just not boot. When I try to boot it I don’t even get to the splash screen, just stuck on a blank purple screen. At this screen when I press f2 there is no verbose output. I've even tried changing the above to `splash` rather than `quiet splash` and there is still no verbose output (yes I updated grub before reboot).

Comment: go ahead and switch it back. as for your question, running the command `less dmesg` will show all that output (easy way to capture . . . ) after you boot so it can be inspected.

Comment: or if running in a regular terminal, just run `dmesg` scroll down to the bottom and scroll back up to inspect

Comment: Cant really tell, but I dont see anything too concerning: http://pastebin.com/r78rLqqL

Comment: does  the command `glxinfo` say direct rendering?

Comment: Wasn't installed. I installed it and yes, it does.

Comment: that's good, now open system settings and select system info. what does this say about the GPU here? it should not say gallium.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it does under System Settings > Details http://imgur.com/OZ2ea8N

Comment: this is the reason for the CPU increase, your gpu is not detected properly so the CPU has to take all the load or at least more than it should. see here http://askubuntu.com/a/186023/167115 and if youneed to create an xorg.conf file you can run the command `sudo Xorg -configure` also make sure xserver-xorg-video-intel is installed and here http://askubuntu.com/a/81039/167115

Comment: Awesome. Looks like you located the problem. It won't install the recommendation above, but I guess thats a seperate question entirely. Thank you! `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: you need to run `sudo apt-get update` first. then run: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: Not the first time I've run into this issue, but in a fresh install I get the following error after those commands. Can't seem to find a solution. http://pastebin.com/df4RZkX9. Also tried to `-f install`.

Comment: Also, `xserver-xorg-core` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` are not installed.